# Angular UI Bootstrap 2.3 Modal is not rendering sightly parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, sightly, htl

I am having a compatibility issue with Angular UI Bootstrap Modal and sightly Parameters. When I try to render the sightly parameters inside the Modal the modal does not render the value in the sightly parameters as:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="stackedModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-{{name}}">${properties.something} </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-{{name}}">
            ${properties.something}
        </div>
    </script>
```

As far as I have observed, there is an issue with printing inside the script tag.
Can someone help me if they have got the same issue?

Modal that I am using is Angular UI Bootstrap verion : 2.3 : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: can you reproduce your problem using plunker or jsfiddle ? also, what exactly do you mean by `sightly parameters` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to provide more context, where your HTML is located? your folder structure and what you are trying to achieve.
Second, Sightly happens on the back-end and Angular in the browser so you should not have incompatibility there, I think your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTL/Sightly includes XSS protection. In this case, for `${properties.something}` the implicit `scriptToken` context is used (https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context) and probably cuts off the content (in case it has characters that are not allowed in that context).

You can probably set a more relaxed context: `${properties.something @ context='html'}`